# How to find out which versions of .Net are registered in IIS

Tags: iis, iis-7

One can use

> aspnet_regiis.exe

in a command line to register the version of with IIS (provided you have cd'd to the correct directory first), this works all well and good

But is there a way to find out which versions are already registered with IIS?

as in, i want to register a version, but im not sure if it already is registered or not. How would i tell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run following checks to verify registered versions:

> aspnet_regiis.exe -lv

Registered framework should return line with location of registered aspnet_isapi.dll

> appcmd.exe list apppool /managedRuntimeVersion:v4.0

This will list all installed app pools for specified runtime version, so if it will return none - runtime is probably not registered.

> appcmd.exe list config -section:system.webServer/isapiFilters

Should return list of registered isapi filters, aspnet_filter.dll being one of them, residing in framework folder, for example "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_filter.dll"

One more possible solution would be to use .net code to scan available application pools and get their runtime versions:

```
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
...
public static bool IsAspNetRegistered(string v = "v4.0")
{
    using (var mgr = new ServerManager())
    {
        return mgr.ApplicationPools.Any(pool => pool.ManagedRuntimeVersion == v);
    }
}
```